# How can I do sorting when pressing on a button

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to press on a button, then, the data retrieve from sqlite will be sorted and display on the ListView. How can I do so?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping);

    sdb = new ShoppingDatabaseHandler(this) ;

    List<Shops> shops = sdb.getAllShops();        
    int count = 0; 
    for ( Shops sp: shops) {

        count++;

    }

    if (count == 0 ){
    sdb.addShopping(new Shops(" Car Market ", " 27454547 ", " 7 ")); 
    sdb.addShopping(new Shops(" ABC MARKET ", " 27872514 ", " 6 ")); 
    sdb.addShopping(new Shops(" Fortress ", " 27454547 ", " 7 ")); 
    }


    Button name = (Button) findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sdb.shopsOrderbyName();
            nameSorting();


        }
    });


    ArrayAdapter<Shops> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Shops>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shops);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}


  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    sdb.close();
    super.onPause();
  }

  public void nameSorting (){

      List<Shops> shops = sdb.getAllShops();     
      ArrayAdapter<Shops> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Shops>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shops);
      shoppingInfo.setAdapter(adapter);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

  }


public void shopsOrderbyName (){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.query(TABLE_SHOP, new String[] { KEY_NAME , KEY_NUMBER , KEY_LOCATION }, null, null, null, null, KEY_NAME+ " ASC");

}
```

So, there are an error when I do the sorting. Thanks for your kindly help.

I did some changes. Am I right ?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping);

    sdb = new ShoppingDatabaseHandler(this) ;

    final List<Shops> shops = sdb.getAllShops();        
    int count = 0; 
    for ( Shops sp: shops) {

        count++;

    }

    if (count == 0 ){
    sdb.addShopping(new Shops(" Car Market ", " 27454547 ", " 7 ")); 
    sdb.addShopping(new Shops(" ABC MARKET ", " 27872514 ", " 6 ")); 
    sdb.addShopping(new Shops(" Fortress ", " 27454547 ", " 7 ")); 
    }

    final ArrayAdapter<Shops> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Shops>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shops);
    Button name = (Button) findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            adapter.clear();
            sdb.shopsOrderbyName();
            nameSorting();
            //List<Shops> sortedShops = sdb.shopsOrderbyName();   
            adapter.addAll(shops);

        }
    });


    //final ArrayAdapter<Shops> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Shops>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shops);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

But there is an error on addall(<>) that there shows a message called "Call requires API level 11". So, what I can due with it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: um...unrelated...you shouldn't be doing any queries on the main thread.

Comment: The shopsOrderbyName () is not placed in main thread, which is placed in database handler.

Comment: post your logcat.. meanwhile Its suggested to perform long running operations such as network or database operations, or computationally expensive calculations such as resizing bitmaps should be done in a worker thread (or in the case of databases operations, via an asynchronous request).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've got your point. If so, it can be done as following:

```
public class Test extends ListActivity {

    ArrayAdapter<Shops> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping);
        sdb = new ShoppingDatabaseHandler(this) ;
        Button name = (Button) findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ArrayList<Shops> shops = sdb.getAllShops();
                Collections.sort(shops, new Comparator<Shops>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Shops lhs, Shops rhs) {
                        return <sort criteria>;
                    }
                });
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Shops>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shops);
                getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of <new sorted list>? What I need to push? Can you explain more for me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am so sorry that what I should change in the onClick function. Because there are some functions I haven't created, what should I do? I am sorry for my stupid

Comment: @user3336747 inside onClick you should pull new data from your DB, then sort this ArrayList using Comparator (about it's usage take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), then create new adapter with sorted data and push it to the listview